# Check whether input is number or not in bash

Tags: bash, numbers

I want to write program to **check whether the given input is number or not**. Can anyone help me?

```
 if [ $Number -ne 0 -o $Number -eq 0 2>/dev/null ]
 then ...
```

and what `-o` stands for in above command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-o` is the **or** operator. So your test check if your number is not equal to 0 or if it's equals to 0.

(so it should always return true).

To check if it's a number, you could use a regexp: this should be working:

```
[[ "$number" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

To see the list of all available flags, you should look at `man test`

---

**Details:**

- `[[` is a extended bash test command. It supports more operator than `test/[`.
- `=~` compare the first argument again a regular expression
- `^[0-9]+$` is the regular expression. `^` is an anchor for the start of the string, `$` for the end.  `[0-9]` means any char between 0 and 9, and `+` is for the repetition of the latest pattern

Comment: thank you what u gave is working fine for my programm.I am new to linux can you please explain the above command given by you?

Comment: update the question with details :)

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX way to do this (for integers; floats are more complicated) is

```
 case $number in
   (*[^0-9]*) printf '%s\n' "not a number";;
   ()         printf '%s\n' "empty";;
   (*)        printf '%s\n' "a number";;
 esac
```

This works for any Bourne shell, unlike the `[[ ... ]]` construct, which is non-portable.